# Angularj JS context menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a context-menu directive that can tell me what was actually clicked so i can react to it.

Was playing with [this](https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu) but the problem of that module is that I can't figure out how to uniquely identify the element that was clicked. So I can do the correct logic on it:

I would need something that I can pass into the callback function

**Controller:**

```
$scope.items.Data = [{Code:'row1', Name:'Name1'},{Code:'row2', Name:'Name2'}]
$scope.items.Actions = [
    {
        Code: 'Action1',
        Name: 'First action'
    },
    {
        Code: 'Action2',
        Name: 'Second action'
    }   
]

var actionList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.Actions.length; i++) {

            actionList.push($scope.items.Actions[i].Name, function ($itemScope,$event) {
                console.log('Action executed', $scope.objectId, $itemScope,$event,$itemScope.$index);
                // Need access to $scope.items.Actions[i].Code or at least the index of the array
            });
}
$scope.contextOptions = actionList;
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Name</td>       
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in items.Data" context-menu="contextOptions">
            <td>{{row.Code}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code including the HTML?

Comment: added more code and basically I need to identify the action that was clicked

Comment: Where is the property `Data` in `$scope.items`??

Comment: @papakia yes as the view suggests

Comment: But your controller does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same thing and have no issue in doing the indexing.
Instead of using

`for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.Actions.length; i++) {}`

Change it to

`$scope.items.Actions.forEach(function(action, index){
     actionList.push(action.Name, function ($itemScope,$event) {
                console.log('Action executed', $scope.objectId, $itemScope,$event,index);
    });
})`

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ty was the solution to my problem